# Git command not working (git checkout -q rewrite)

Tags: git

I just tried using git and I get some error I don't know why

Here's what the errror says:

error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git
Command "git checkout -q rewrite" failed with error code 1

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry its just I'm not finding a solution to fix this error for like 2 hours now and I'm really done with it

Comment: I have edited it, thanks phd

Answer (score 0):

You are asking git to checkout branch rewrite in 'quiet' mode... that means that the branch must exist locally already. Is that the case? Probably not. If you want git to create the branch locally from the remote branch of the same name, use `-b` instead of `-q`

Comment: I mean, I'm just trying to setup something and it does everything automacially so I don't think I can do -c instead of -q?

Comment: They are not the same. If the branch does not exist and you want git to create it, it's -c. If the branch exists already (apparently not, right) then you have to create it before hand if you don't use -b.

Comment: Did I say -c? It's -b.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout` switches to a branch that has already been created. To see the list of branches locally, run `git branch`. To create a branch, run `git branch <new_branch>` where `<new_branch>` is the name of the branch to be createed. Once the branch exists locally, it can be checked it out.

Creating a branch and checking it out can be combined into a single command with `git checkout -B <new_branch>`

`git help checkout` will give more information about the checkout command.